# Angular2-seed to production?

Tags: angular

I’m learning about Angular2 right now and I’ve been using the Angular2-seed project on Github (https://github.com/angular/angular2-seed) as a starting point for my app.

All seems to be working well and I’d like to move the app to Azure to make sure it works in a production environment, but I’m unsure what I need to do in order to configure the files etc? Looking in the project folder, the .js files are not being produced from the .ts files, so I’m confused as to how the app is running in the first place! Is there some sort of JIT compilation happening from the webpack server?

Comment: Does it have some kind of build or compile option? If not, try the Angular CLI, which does. Otherwise you'll have to run the node app in production rather than just serving static HTML and JS.

Answer (score 0):

Webpack compiles all the TS files and serves them through the local NodeJs web server. If you want to deploy, build it with:

```
npm run build
```

Then take the generated files, copy them to an Azure web site, and it's done.

Comment: Thanks, but what do I take? The new 'dist' folder only contains .js and .map files, so do I put them into the relevant folders in the 'src' folder and copy that to Azure?

Comment: No. you take the contents of the "dist" directory only and put that in Azure. That is your compiled application.

Comment: But there are no html files in the dist folder, and no sub folders.

Comment: @usefulshrimp did you find answer to this? I am in same situation. dist doesnt even have index.html file.